# Twitter Bootstrap Background image not showing on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

[image: Here is the hierarchy of my ubuntu desktop]              I am working on twitter bootstrap on my localhost(xampp) on ubuntu linux,I have tried a lot to load the background image for the website but nothing seems to work.I have the image in the same folder as my php file.I have included all the bootstrap cdn but its not working.Is it the url problem?

Here is the link to code on JSbin http://jsbin.com/nudemorune/edit?html 
Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: correct the url of image

Comment: Do not format regular text as code to cheat the requirement that a link to a fiddle/bin site must be accompanied by actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for not showing the background image might be the CSS is not getting the image. I mean your background image path is not correct. Try to do this:

```
#topcontainer{

            background-image:url("../img-directory-name/background.jpg");
            height:400px;
}
```

Comment: I tried to put in the location but it is still not working,the image is in var/www/html/tempboot ....ie tempboot is the directory in which i have my actual php as well as the image in the same location.What maybe the problem

Comment: Can you please provide me your project hierarchy? Location of your CSS file?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of my server files

Comment: `#topcontainer{

            background-image:url("../background.jpg");
            height:400px;
}`